# when text = 'Text' in a worksheet, insert "XXX" on adjacent cell, then cut & paste whole rows onto another worksheet & loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro - when text = 'Text' in a worksheet, insert "XXX" on adjacent cell, then cut & paste whole rows onto another worksheet & loop till all relevant rows have been cut - please can someone help...?

Comment: Pleae be more specific. Show us input and desired output. Also, what is relevant row?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which line of your code is not working?

Comment: I want to find a specific word within a worksheet, & if present, I want to cut the whole row it sits on, paste onto next w/sheet & loop the command so that the deleted rows can be added together to create another w/sheet…? …Please…
I’m extremely rusty  - I haven’t written any code or programmes in years  - I used to be able to write complex programmes within SAS & VB – I think I’m just nervous about getting this right…

Answer (score 0):

**I am not 100% understand your question but I hope this code work for you.
I try to make it easy and I made notes on the code**

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    'make command button .. it is better

    Dim ContainWord1 As String
    Dim finalrow As Integer
    Dim x As Integer


  finalrow = Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row
    'What phrase do you want to test for?
      ContainWord1 = "Text"



    'Loop through each cell in range and test cell contents

      For x = 2 To finalrow
 'you can change the columns to fit your worksheet
      If Sheet1.Cells(x, 1).Value = ContainWord1 Then Sheet1.Cells(x, 1).EntireRow.Cut Sheet2.Range("A100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

      Next x
    End Sub
```

Comment: Be careful with your variables. You declare `ContainWord` but then use `ContainWord1`. This could've been enforced by using `Option Explicit` at the top of your module - good practice to get into the habit of. This will also break if OP has more then 100 `'Text'` values

Comment: Thanks so much guys  -

Comment: The code immediately above falls over when it gets to:

Comment: finalrow = Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row

Answer (score 0):

Use `Find` and `FindNext`. Update the commented values to your `Source`/`Destination`

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub FindTestValues()
    Dim Destination As Worksheet, Source As Worksheet
    Dim TestColumn As Long
    Dim FirstAddress As String, FindValue As String
    Dim c As Range

    ' Set source and destination worksheets
    Set Source = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Source")
    Set Destination = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Destination")

    ' Column that contains 'Test' value
    TestColumn = 2
    ' Set what you want to find to variable
    FindValue = "Text"

    Set c = Source.Columns(TestColumn).Find(what:=FindValue, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        Do
            With Destination
                c.EntireRow.Cut Destination:=.Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, TestColumn).End(xlUp).Row, 1).Offset(1, 0)
            End With
            Set c = Source.Columns(TestColumn).FindNext
        Loop Until c Is Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```